# Searching "Android" on Android Enthusiasts in the Android App Returns No Results

Tags: bug, android-app

**Issue 1:**

Maybe I'm completely missing something here or my eyes are deceiving me, but when I search for the word "Android" in Android Enthusiasts, no results are returned in the app. When I search the same thing on the actual website, there are plenty of results. In the app, if I add something to the search, for example searching "Android g" it returns results containing the word "Android". I thought it might occur on all sites on the app but searching "Android" in SO returns results. Is anyone else able to reproduce this?

**Issue 2:**

I also noticed something else when I came across this. Usually, when you switch between the Relevant, Votes, Active, Newest options beside the search field it reloads those questions. When no results are returned (as in the issue above) and you switch, from, lets say Votes to Active (or any combination) it does not reload the questions for that option. Instead the no results message is still displayed. If for some reason the first issue can't be reproduced you should still be able to reproduce this one by searching for some random string that would return no results.

I'm on version 0.1.74

Comment: Could this because single-word searches are converted to a tag search and the "android" tag is black-listed on Android Enthusiasts?

Comment: Do you know of any other single word tags that are black-listed on any of the sites that could be tested?

Comment: Shouldn't it find all questions?  And, as such, would it be any different than the main page?

Comment: I was expecting it to at least find some and couldn't think of a reason it wouldn't. @AlEverett may be correct though, I'm sure we'll find out.

Comment: The name of most SE2.0 sites are blacklisted on their respective sites I believe. I know for a fact that [pets] is blacklisted on Pets.SE. Don't have the App to test though

Comment: @psubsee2003 I am able to search "Programmers" and get results on the Programmers site on the app (not sure if its black listed though). I'm not confirming out denying your suggestion though.

Comment: [Biology] is blacklisted on Biology but searching for Biology gives results

Comment: It's a very old post, but I couldn't repro on v1.0.82 (beta). 1) I could search "android" on [android.se], 2) somethings has certainly changed, since there's no "*no results*" message now; the app only shows blank result.