# Android app Search returns incomplete results

Tags: bug, search, android-app

On math.stackexchange, I did a search for `exception user:25554` (25554 being my user number), looking for a particular post.  The app did not find it.  But when I search on the web site with a web browser, the web site search *did* find it; it's [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/606597/how-or-why-does-intutionistic-logic-proof-negations-from-within-the-theory-cons/608175#608175).

> [image: screenshot of failed search]

In fact the Android app found only five posts, but [the same search on the web site](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=+exception++user%3A25554) produces sixty posts.

[Comments in this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202631/searching-android-on-android-enthusiasts-in-the-android-app-returns-no-results) suggest that one-word searches are converted to tag searches. That does not appear to be the case here.  A search for `throws exception user:25554` on the Android app finds nothing, but [on the web site finds two posts](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=+throws+exception++user%3A25554), including the one I was looking for.

My device is a Samsung GT-I8190N (“Galaxy S3 mini”) running Android 4.1.2.

I am using the SE Android App Version 1.0.26.

Comment: Currently (due to technical reasons, I guess) the app is searching only questions and not answers. And indeed, the full site search [limited to questions only](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=+exception++user%3A25554+is%3Aquestion), returns the same results. It's already [reported here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220588/searching-by-user-id-in-android-app-only-shows-questions-no-answers) and planned to be fixed.

Comment: Very good, thanks!  I hope this question can be quickly closed as a duplicate of the other.